# More elegant regex to number repeated instances of the same declared variable name in Intellij

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

Here is my situation:

```
  val crimson = C("#DC143C", (220, 20, 60), 3937500)
  val lightpink = C("#FFB6C1", (255, 182, 193), 12695295)
  val lightpink = C("#FFAEB9", (255, 174, 185), 12168959)
  val lightpink = C("#EEA2AD", (238, 162, 173), 11379438)
  val lightpink = C("#CD8C95", (205, 140, 149), 9800909)
  val lightpink = C("#8B5F65", (139, 95, 101), 6643595)
  val pink = C("#FFC0CB", (255, 192, 203), 13353215)
  val pink = C("#FFB5C5", (255, 181, 197), 12957183)
  val pink = C("#EEA9B8", (238, 169, 184), 12102126)
  val pink = C("#CD919E", (205, 145, 158), 10392013)
  val pink = C("#8B636C", (139, 99, 108), 7103371)
  val palevioletred = C("#DB7093", (219, 112, 147), 9662683)
  val palevioletred = C("#FF82AB", (255, 130, 171), 11240191)
  val palevioletred = C("#EE799F", (238, 121, 159), 10451438)
  val palevioletred = C("#CD6889", (205, 104, 137), 9005261)
  val palevioletred = C("#8B475D", (139, 71, 93), 6113163)
  val lavenderblush = C("#FFF0F5", (255, 240, 245), 16118015)
  val lavenderblush = C("#EEE0E5", (238, 224, 229), 15065326)
  val lavenderblush = C("#CDC1C5", (205, 193, 197), 12960205)
  val lavenderblush = C("#8B8386", (139, 131, 134), 8815499)
  val violetred = C("#FF3E96", (255, 62, 150), 9846527)
  val violetred = C("#EE3A8C", (238, 58, 140), 9190126)
  val violetred = C("#CD3278", (205, 50, 120), 7877325)
  val violetred = C("#8B2252", (139, 34, 82), 5382795)
```

This goes on for thousands of lines.

Now I want to do the following: if there is only one of that `val ...` I want to leave it, but if there is more than one, I want to number each one starting with the first `lightpink1` and until `lightpinkN`.

Here is my best idea so far :(

So this will match the first occurrence...

```
(?:^.*val (\w+).*\n)
```

Then subsequent occurrences can be caught via backreference:

```
(?:^.*val (\w+).*\n)(?:^.*val (\1).*\n)+
```

**Edit** I found a better way...

```
val (\w+) =(?=.*\n.*val \1 = )
```

will find the first of many repeated occurences.

But then I need to do the replacement...

This is where I am getting stuck, because I can only think to perhaps split the string into parts and permute every case (1 copy, 2, 3, 4,... maybe upt 15).

Is there another way?

Comment: There is a feature to add counters in Emacs and Funduc S&R software. I am not sure it is possible to do that in IntelliJ.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thx but I am kind tweaking on this problem now

Comment: I guess getting them in blocks with [`^val\ (\w+).+[\n\r](?:val\ \1.+[\n\r]?)+`](https://regex101.com/r/cD4oU2/1) and analyzing/numbering them programatically afterwards will lead you to an end faster.

Comment: I ended up doing that but what i Wanted was... a way to do something like `.*needle.*\n.*(needleBackref)+` but i dont know how you can count in regex